# autostart a launchfile after/while boot

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I looking for a solution to just turn on my system (ubuntu 11.04 server/headless) and launch a launchfile automatically.

I tried the solution posted [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11753/ros-autostart-with-daemontools/) with a boot startup script but it didn't work.
Would be great to get your thoughts.

here is my script in /etc/init.d/:

```
start_ros () {
#Get ROS bash commands
  source /opt/ros/electric/setup.sh
#Get custom packages (this script will launch with 'sudo', so it'll be the root user
  export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/panda:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
#Home directory of your user for logging
  export HOME="/home/panda"
#Home directory for your user for logging
  export ROS_HOME="/home/panda/.ros"

#I run ROS on a headless machine, so I want to be able to connect to it remotely
  export ROS_IP="192.168.9.123"
#I like to log things, so this creates a new log for this script
  LOG="/var/log/panda.log"

#Time/Date stamp the log
  echo -e "\n$(date +%Y:%m:%d-%T) - Starting ROS daemon at system startup" >> $LOG
  echo "This launch will export ROS's IP as $ip" >> $LOG

#For bootup time calculations
  START=$(date +%s.%N)

#This is important. You must wait until the IP address of the machine is actually configured by all of the Ubuntu process. Otherwise, you will get an error and launch will fail. This loop just loops until the IP comes up. 
  while true; do
        IP="`ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'192.168.9.123''| cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`"

        if [ "$IP" ] ; then
                echo "Found"
                break
        fi
  done
#For bootup time calculations
  END=$(date +%s.%N)

  echo "It took $(echo "$END - $START"|bc ) seconds for an IP to come up" >> $LOG

  echo "Launching default_package default_launch into a screen with name 'ros'." >> $LOG
  screen -dmS ros roslaunch panda_cam high.launch

}

case "$1" in
  start)
        start_ros
esac

exit 0
```

after that I called and rebooted

```
$sudo update-rc.d panda_cam_startup defaults 99
```

while bootup i get the following output

```
/etc/rc2.d/S99panda_cam_startup: 45: source: not found 
Found
/etc/rc2.d/S99panda_cam_startup: 45: bc: not found
/etc/rc2.d/S99panda_cam_startup: 45: screen: not found
```

But the sourcepath is definitely righ. No idea whats wrong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52044/autostart-a-launchfile-after/while-boot/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2013-01-11

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2013-01-11**:
Maybe you can get some inspiration from here: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/tree/master/turtlebot_bringup/upstart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [ros-system-daemon-groovy](https://github.com/TurtleBot-Mfg/ros-system-daemon-groovy). That is a recent package that should do what you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2013-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2013-01-13**:
Is the name indicating the ROS version compatibility? I'm using electric...

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2013-01-13**:
It looks like a lot of the files reference groovy specifically, but, if you changed that, after a quick glance it looks like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An old question, but others may also be interested in our just-released [robot_upstart](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/robot_upstart) package.

It's along the same line as ros-system-daemon, but more directly modelled after the scripts in turtlebot_bringup. Clearpath will definitely be supporting it going forward, as Husky, Grizzly, and Kingfisher's bring up packages all depend on it.

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2013-08-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2013-11-10**:
Will it work for groovy? I notice the branch name is called 'hydro-devel'.